# how to include urlpatterns in django?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

In my project I have one app which have its own urls.py like this

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^(?P<language>\w+)/$', 'MainSite.views.home_page'),)
```

(above file is in my application )

I am trying include this file in main(project's) urls.py
like this :

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'', include('myproject.MainSite.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.DEBUG :
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', 
{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        )
```

but after this I can able to call the MainSite's (app's) view but my admin url is not working 
I tried

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^$', include('myproject.MainSite.urls')),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

but after this this makes admin work but my app's view won't get called,
how do I solve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're including your views at the root level. Since it comes before the urlpattern for the admin, the first urlpattern catches *everything*, so nothing is ever passed to the admin views.

The simplest fix is to simply reverse the order:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'', include('myproject.MainSite.urls')),
)
```

Then, your views will only catch anything the admin doesn't.

Comment: @abhishekworld you might consider accepting the answer.